# Change side-figure name and numbering

Tags: floats, numbering, sidecap

I'm writing my thesis and I have one Chapter that is a step by step instruction manual.  I'm using the package `sidecap` to get a figure on the outside of the page with caption beside it.  What's getting generated now is a caption that's labeled with `Figure <chapter_no>.<fig_no>`.

What I'd like is if the caption was labeled with `Step <section_no>.<fig_no>`.  I also don't want them appearing in my  list of figures either.

EDIT: I'm okay with using a different package for side captions as well.

EDIT: here's my minimal example.  note that right now example-image-a is captioned `Figure 2.1:...`  and I'd prefer `Step 1.1` as it's in section 1 (of ch2) and it's the first figure.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{My first chapter}
    \lipsum[4]
    \chapter{My second chapter}
    \section{ the first section}
    \lipsum[2]
    \begin{SCfigure}[][h]
        \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption[short cap]{hello world}
    \end{SCfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please can you post a minimal example document which demonstrates what you get now so we know where to start? This should start with `\documentclass` and will certainly include a few `\usepackage` commands as you'll need `sidecap`, at least. And end with `\end{document}`. It will, obviously, need to include a figure or two to demonstrate the issue. If you want sample images, load `graphicx` and then say `\includegraphics{example-image-a` `b` and `c` are other exciting alternatives to `a`. This will ensure everyone can compile your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `newfloat` for defining a float type independent of `figure`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{sidecap}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  fileext=los,
  listname={List of Steps},
  name=Step,
  placement=htp,
  within=section,% steps are reset with sections
]{step}
\renewcommand{\thestep}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{step}}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{My second chapter}

\section{The first section}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{SCstep}[][h]
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
\caption[short cap]{hello world}
\end{SCstep}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{Example figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You can check that the list of figures only contain the figure and not the “Step”.

[image]

Comment: This is pretty close!  the first number after step is still the chapter number and not the section number.

Comment: @user1816847 Check now